# Do I need an "EMR" to use the paddles on a Scuf controller?

Tags: pc, controllers

[Scuf](https://scufgaming.com) is one of the top brands of third-party, professional-quality controllers for gaming.  Their controllers all come with back paddles.

During checkout, it asks if I want "EMR" for an extra $15.  I can't find *anywhere* on their site what this means.  Based on [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/scufgaming/comments/fb2iln/is_emr_necessary_for_scuff_impact/) it's just a magnetic sensor that's necessary for remapping the back paddles.  However that sounds completely insane because

1. Why would they need a magnet for that? and
2. That would mean the back paddles are completely useless without an EMR.

So, **what actually is the EMR? And can I use the back-paddles without it?**

I am on PC, where I would expect the paddles to just register as separate buttons.

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer, but their website page [here](https://customercare.scufgaming.com/hc/en-us/articles/360048904571-Features-How-do-I-remap-my-SCUF-Infinity1-paddles-) says "*Note: Electro-Magnetic Remapping is an optional feature available if selected at time of purchase. If EMR was not selcted, paddles will be permanently mapped to (from left to right) A, X, Y, B.*"  Sounds like unless you want to move around the A, X, Y, B mapping, you need to get this.  But if you don't ever want to swap these, you don't need it.  There's also a small video on that page about it.